# @ViewChild not defined in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, viewchild

I am facing a problem with *ngIf and @ViewChild. I tried most of the recommended solutions on the other questions of this type but nothing worked for me.

My HTML file is as below:

```html
<div id="main-container" class="page-layout blank p-24" fusePerfectScrollbar fxLayout="column">
  <mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event);" fxLayout="row wrap">

     <mat-tab label="Some1" *ngIf="arrayNames.includes('Some1')">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                <my-table #table></my-table>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab label="Some2" *ngIf="arrayNames.includes('Some2')">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                <my-table #table></my-table>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab label="Some3" *ngIf="arrayNames.includes('Some3')">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                <my-table #table></my-table>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
   </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

In my component ts file I have the following:

```js
  matTabs = [1, 2, 3]; 
  @ViewChild('tabGroup', {static: false}) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;
  data: Array<SomeEntity> = [];
  arrayNames: Array<string> = [];
  @ViewChild('table', { static: false }) table: AnotherComponent;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getAll()
    .subscribe((result) => {
      this.data = result;
      for (let d of this.data) {
        this.arrayNames.push(d.name);
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selectedTabLabel = this.tabGroup?._tabs?.first.textLabel;
    this.TabChangeService.changeTab(this.selectedTabLabel);
    this.table.displayMyTable();
  }
```

The '**table**' child always comes as undefined. Is there any way I can modify this so I can show the data on the first mat-tab after the view has initialized?

When the page finished loading it shows like this:
[image]

because **this.table.displayMyTable();** does not display anything since the 'this.table is undefined'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *ngIf can you try using the hidden property of the html tag that may solve the problem. The problem I think is that the html dom doesn't have the ngif elements thus giving this error when you are trying to access this element in your Typescript file.
Your code then should be -

```
 <mat-tab label="Some1" [hidden]="!arrayNames.includes('Some1')">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <my-table #table></my-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Some2" [hidden]="!arrayNames.includes('Some2')">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <my-table #table></my-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Some3" [hidden]="!arrayNames.includes('Some3')">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <my-table #table></my-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
```

Comment: This worked for me in my situation with a dynamic @viewchild component not rendering after its parent was hidden then shown by an ngIf statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you can consider trying:

First of them: Surround this.table with setTimeout

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selectedTabLabel = this.tabGroup?._tabs?.first.textLabel;
    this.TabChangeService.changeTab(this.selectedTabLabel);
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.table.displayMyTable();
    })
  }
```

Second attempt: Change the ViewChild to ViewChildren

```js
  @ViewChildren('table') table: QueryList<AnotherComponent>;
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with Stackblitz? It'll be easier to help you

Comment: Before it, you can try it:  @ViewChild(AnotherComponent, { static: false }) table: AnotherComponent;